# Объединить 2 правила

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)+$ index.php?do=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)+$ index.php?do=$1&po=$2 [QSA]
```

Каким образом возможно объединить 2 данных правила в одно.
Адреса могут быть:

```
/ttewe
/tett/eeee
```

Второй вопрос, есть

```
RewriteRule ^s-(.*)$ index.php?do=s&po=$1 [QSA]
```

Но оно так же обрабатывает такие адреса, например

```
/s-аа/text
```

А необходимо, чтобы подобные адреса игнорировались, то есть со вторым каталогом не учитывались. Если есть дом get параметры через символ `?` Необходимо обрабатывать, или просто адрес `/s-` Тоже должно брать вовнимание.

На данный момент все работает как необходимо, единственное берет адреса в которых есть второй каталог...